# Reproducing the new array from existing array(multi array)

Tags: php

Reproducing the new array from existing array(multi array)

If I have an array called as parameter:

```
$arr =  Array
          (
          [0] => Array(0,Array(0=>'abc'))
          [1] => Array(0,Array(1=>'def'))
          [2] => Array(1,Array(0=>'ghi'))
    )
```

Want to to a function that pass $arr some thing like this

```
function TODO($arr){
      //
      return $new_array;
 }
```

And the function will return 
RESULT WILL BE Reproduce elements from previous array ,And it will be got the result(returned):

```
Array
    (
       [0] => Array
           (
              [0] => 'abc'
              [1] => 'def'
            )

       [1] => Array
           (
               [0] => 'ghi'
            )

    )
```

Anybody know how to do this?Please

thanks

Comment: Could you give a few more examples of how this function should process the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I've understood what you want, but if I have, this should work:

```
<?php

$arr = Array(
    0 => Array(0, Array(0=>'abc')),
    1 => Array(0, Array(1=>'def')),
    2 => Array(1, Array(0=>'ghi'))
);


function transformArray($array) {
    $newArray = array();

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (!isset($newArray[$value[0]])) {
            $newArray[$value[0]] = array();
        }
        $newArray[$value[0]][] = array_pop($value[1]);
    }

    return $newArray;
}


$outputArray = transformArray($arr);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($outputArray, true) . '</pre>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. If you have controll over how these text arrays are turned into text, you should use `serialize()` and `unserialize()`. The fastest and easiest way.

If you still need to create arrays from the strings you have provided, you will probably have to construct quite a complex function to do that.

Comment: What do the 0 or 1 do before the array?